# Replace multiple characters at once using Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I have a lot of files with contains characters like:

```
ª º ã þ Þ
```

in random order, inserted in words and I want to change the encoding of text from Central European to UTF8 and replace these characters with corresponding UTF8 characters:

```
Ș ș ă ț Ț
```

I want to replace all the characters in one pass using RegularExpressions in SublimeText2 and unfortunately I don't know how to do this. The only thing I get is this:

Find: (ª)

Replace: $1Ș

If knows somebody how to incorporate all characters (ª º ã þ Þ) into the Find dialog please post.

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. It is a bug to treat all 8-bit encodings as ISO-8859-1, let alone as the proprietary Microsoft Windows® Code Page 1252. You need to open the file using the proper encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you have a set of files which at the moment are correctly encoded in one character encoding (say, ISO 8859-2) and you want to convert those files so that they are encoded in UTF-8?

If that is what you're trying to do, Find/Replace is totally the wrong way to do it.   Just use a program like `recode` or `iconv`.